# Auf welcher Stilebene ist die Konstruktion "[Verb] tut es (nicht)" anzusiedeln?

Tags: word-usage

Im mündlichen Sprachgebrauch ist folgende Konstruktion oftmals anzutreffen:

> Aussehen tut es wie Fleisch, ist es aber nicht.
>
> Wenn es nicht hilft, schaden tut es auch nicht.
>
> Schmecken tut es mir nicht besonders.

Ist solche Ausdruckweise nur in der Umgangssprache gebräuchlich oder kann man sie auch im Schriftverkehr einsetzen, ohne dass sich der Satz ungehobelt/familiär anhört?

Ist diese Konstruktion überhaupt umganssprachlich?

Comment: Achtung, Hupalarm!

Comment: @tofro Was ist ein Hupalarm?

Comment: @Thomas Ein Hupalarm ist ein Alarm, der ertönt, wenn es **tutet**. Das war ein Ausspruch meiner Deutschlehrerin.

Comment: Beispielsatz Nummer 1 ist syntaktisch defizitär. Korrekt wäre theoretisch: *Aussehen tut es wie Fleisch, sein tut es das aber nicht*. Natürlich nur, wenn man ***etwas tun tun*** überhaupt als zulässige Fügung ansieht.

Answer (score 7):

Die Verbindung aus Infinitiv und »tun« ist ein Element der Kindersprache.

> Wer nicht essen tut, wird auch nicht groß.

Vorteil: Das Kind hört keine Konjugationen (hier: »isst«). Das reduziert die kindliche Verwirrung.

Aber auch in der Erwachsenensprache hat diese Konstruktion ihr Recht, z. B. wenn ein Verb hervorgehoben werden soll.

> Aussehen tut er gut, er hat aber kein Geld.

In diesem Fall ist die Konstruktion mehr Stilmittel als Umgangssprache.

Comment: Schöne Erklärung mit der Kindersprache, hast du dafür eine wissenschaftliche Referenz?

Comment: @Thomas: Leider nein, das wäre eine Frage für sich.

Comment: Lesenswert dazu: http://www.blogigo.de/Morlocks/Das-Hilfsverb-tun-./3808/
Übrigens ist es dann ein Hilfsverb: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hilfsverb#Andere_W%C3%B6rter_in_Hilfsverb-Funktion

Answer (score 5):

Die Konstruktion ist nicht sehr elegant sondern eher holprig. Im gesprochenen Wort wird sie wahrscheinlich häufiger vorkommen, da man hier beim Reden oft das Verb in seiner Grundform voran stellt und mit dem Hilfsverb „tun“ diesen Satzbaufehler ausgleichen kann. Im Schriftverkehr sollte man es meist vermeiden und den Satz umstellen.

Hier die, meiner Meinung nach, schöneren Varianten der Beispielsätze:

- Es sieht aus wie Fleisch, ist es aber nicht.
- Wenn es nicht hilft, es schadet auch nicht.
- Es schmeckt mir nicht besonders.

Eine kleine Ausnahme ist vielleicht der zweite Satz: „Schaden tut es nicht“ würde ich fast schon als feste Redewendung einstufen.

Comment: Vielleicht ist es weil ich Niederländer bin, aber für mich klingt "Wenn es nicht hilft, schadet es auch nicht" besser. Oder liege ich da falsch? Man sagt ja auch nicht "Wenn du das nicht möchtest, dann ich komme nicht mit", oder? Ich würde sagen "dann komme ich nicht mit".

Comment: @RudyVelthuis: Beide Sätze haben eine leicht unterschiedliche Aussage: "(Auch) Wenn es nicht hilft, es schadet auch nicht" bedeutet dass das Mittel auf jeden Fall nicht schadet, es könnte aber helfen. "Wenn es nicht hilft, schadet es auch nicht" bedeutet, dass ein Mittel das nicht hilft auch nicht schadet (z.B. weil es keinerlei Wirkung hat).

Comment: Nein, das sehe ich anders. Für mich bedeutet "Wenn es nicht hilft, schadet es auch nicht" dass "es" hilfreich sein kann, aber wenn nicht, dass es dann wenigstens nicht schadet.

Answer (score 5):

Den ersten Satz würde ich sowohl mit als auch ohne '*tut*' anders formulieren: *Aussehen tut es wie Fleisch, es ist aber keins.* Auch den zweiten Satz würde ich anders bringen: *Auch wenn es wenig hilft, schaden tut es jedenfalls nicht.* Das sind letztlich Geschmacksfragen.

Im Gegensatz zu vielen anderen an der deutschen Sprache Interessierten bin ich pro Umgangssprache eingestellt. Sätze mit 'tut es' sind für mich in entsprechenden Kontexten völlig akzeptabel. Satz 3 funktioniert für meine Begriffe nur in der gesprochenen Sprache: *Wenn du mich fragst: Also das Dessert ist ein echter Hingucker, aber schmecken tut es mir nicht besonders.*

Was die Bewertung von Stilmitteln und Stilebenen angeht, wird man kaum auf einen gemeinsamen Nenner kommen. Umgangssprachliche Elemente und ein etwas frecherer Schreibstil sind mittlerweile im Journalismus gang und gäbe, dennoch würde kein Journalist einen Text durchgängig in Umgangssprache abfassen. Früher hat man mal gelernt: 'Tuen tut man nicht benutzen!'. In meiner Gegend waren damit so Sätze wie 'ich tu inne Sonne liegen' gemeint. Bei eher traditionell und sprachpflegerisch veranlagten Menschen hat sich so eine Regel dahingehend verselbständigt, dass 'tun' als 'Hilfsverb' überhaupt nicht verwendet werden 'sollte'. Naja, wenn's denen Spaß macht...

Ich halte etwa den Fall 1 (*Aussehen tut es wie Fleisch*) für eine umgangssprachennahe Möglichkeit, um durch betonte Voranstellung auszudrücken, dass etwas einen falschen optischen Anschein erweckt. Ein Satz wie *'geärgert hatte mich das schon!'* wäre demgegenüber stilistisch unbedenklich, obwohl er auf demselben Mechanismus von betonter Voranstellung basiert, nur weil er kein '*tun*' enthält?

Comment: Wo genau siehst du den grammatikalischen Unterschied zwischen "Ich tu in der Sonne liegen" (das du abwertest) und "Aussehen tut es wie Fleisch", (das du für zulässig hältst)?

Comment: Die Duden-Grammatik 2006 schreibt auf Seite 434 unter Rz 594: "In der geschriebenen Standardsprache wird es [= das Hilfsverb 'tun'] nur dann verwendet, wenn das Vollverb zum Zweck der Hervorhebung ins Vorfeld eines Verbzweitsatzes gestellt werden soll und kein anderes infinitregierendes Verb vorhanden ist: _Verstehen tut er wie gewöhnlich nichts._" Bei "Ich tu in der Sonne liegen" steht das Verb 'liegen' nicht im Vorfeld. Der Duden spricht wohlgemerkt von geschriebener Standardsprache.

Answer (score 5):

Die Verwendung von "tun" als Hilfsverb (das ist hier der Fall) ist vollständig umgangssprachlich.

In Schriftform hat so eine Konstruktion nichts zu suchen.

Comment: Da tust du recht haben!

Comment: Nö, recht haben tut er nicht. :-)

Answer (score 4):

Es ist mit Sicherheit umgangssprachlich, aber man kann es m.E. auch in Schrift benutzen.

Das Verb *tun* wird hier quasi als Hilfsverb benutzt, um den Infinitiv am Satzanfang zu platzieren, also gewissermaßen als Stilelement um den Infinitiv zu betonen.

Ich sehe und höre dieses Konstrukt eigentlich meistens als Antwort auf eine Frage, ähnlich wie

> "Was ist es eigentlich?"
>   "Aussehen tut es wie Fleisch, es ist aber keins."

Natürlich könnte man auch sagen

> "Es sieht aus wie Fleisch..." usw.

aber das betont das Wort *aussehen* nicht so schön.

Comment: "Tun" ist kein deutsches Hilfs- oder Modalverb, kann deshalb auch nicht als solches benutzt werden. Tut man es trotzdem, ist es umgangssprachlich. Natürlich kann man Umgangssprache auch aufschreiben. "Falsch" ist sie trotzdem.

Comment: @tofro Ist Umgangssprache keine Sprache? Ich glaube schon, daß es ein Hilfsverb ist, siehe mein Kommentar oben mit Verlinkung.

Comment: @Thomas Ich habe nirgendwo geschrieben, das Umgangssprache keine Sprache sei. Und nein, "tun" wird im Standarddeutsch kein Hilfsverb, nur weil das in irgendeinem Blog steht. Und die Formulierung in der Wikipedia willst du nochmal lesen.

Comment: @tofro: Ich gebe zu bedenken: https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/tun_werden

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Ja - Da steht "umgangssprachlich, landschaftlich"

Comment: @tofro: Jetzt bitte genau sein. Da steht nur "landschaftlich" für die Konjunktiv-Variante, und "umgangssprachlich" nur für die Variante mit dem *nachgestellten* Infinitiv, nicht für die Variante wo das Infinitiv vorangestellt wird. Und um genau diese letztere Variante handelt die Frage ("Aussehen tut es..."), und genau diese Variante wird in meiner Antwort besprochen. Der Duden meint offensichtlich auch, dass das zur Betonung ein legitimes Stilelement ist.

Comment: @tofro: Bliebe zu erwähnen, dass die Duden-Redaktion über ihre verschiedenen Produkte hinweg (Rechtschreibung, Grammatik, Online-Ausgabe...) nicht immer 'konsistent' (hatten wir grade) argumentiert, in diesem Fall jedoch schon. Außerdem ändern sich solche Bewertungen im Lauf der Zeit, und dies nicht im Gleichschritt der Regionen, sozialen Verbände und Altersklassen. Ältere Sprachteilnehmer haben da naturgemäß oft eine konservativere Haltung. Sowieso: Die Meinung der Duden-Macher ist eben auch nur eine Meinung, man muss sich ihr nicht anschließen. 'Tu' ich hier aber.

Comment: Rudy, das Einzige, was mich an deiner Antwort stört, ist, dass du im zweiten Absatz "tun" als Hilfsverb bezeichnest, sonst nix. Es mag *im Ausnahmefall* die Funktion eines solchen übernehmen können, generell ist es aber keins. Machst du das "Hilfs-" weg, ist es eine perfekte Antwort. So ist sie irreführend.

Comment: @tofro: Besser so (siehe Edit)?

Comment: Ja, viel besser.